# Proper way to store and clear cookie in Laravel with Cypress Testing

Tags: laravel, cookies, cypress

I have brought cypress into a Laravel app and am doing some testing with `axios.post` requests. I have figured out how to get cypress to work in terms of `preserving` the `xsrf token` so that the `axios` call can finish it's process. The issue is that when I attempt to clear the cookie in the localized test it does not work. The next time I open the test my user is already logged into their account so the cookie is not being reset each time the test runs. Am I doing this improperly?

Cypress/Support/index.js

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    preserve: ["XSRF-TOKEN", "myapp_session", "remember_token"]
});
```

Inside of an `it()` in my cypress test. At this point the user is authenticated and a form is being filled out. This is the point of form submission on click. When the button is clicked an `axios.post()` request is sent. The post is working as expected, again I just want to user to have to re-authenticate once the test restarts.

```
 //Submit the form
        cy.get('[data-cy=system-create-submit]').click()

        cy.wait(4500)

        cy.location('pathname').should('eq', '/system')

        //cy.getCookie('myapp_session') // clear the 'myapp_session' cookie
        //Update as of 10.29.21
        cy.clearCookie('myapp_session')
```

If I close and open + restart the test the user is still authenticated even though the first step in the test is to log the user in.

EDIT: Placing the `clearCookie()` command at the very end of my test worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the command you are looking for is

```js
cy.clearCookie('myapp_session')
```

Comment: I updated my code and tested and each time I run the test the cookie is still not cleared. Do I need to set the clearCookie command at the beginning of the test?

Comment: I simply put it at the end of my test. But you could also put it into a ```afterEach``` command. It did work for me, even though I also use preserve cookies in a ```beforeEach```